# LM4510 Switching Converter not working

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, buck

I am using a TI LM4510 converter [(datasheet)](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm4510.pdf) to step up from 5V to 12V (adjustable). I have good input power, enabled chip, and followed datasheet, but the output voltage is actually lower than the input. I've attached the schematic and board footprint. Any ideas on what's going on?

Thanks in advance!

[image: Schematic]

[image: Footprint]

Comment: You checked that the EN pin is actually pulling high? For some types of logic (and the logic in a device like this might not conform to any particular standard), 100k is too weak a pull-up to reliably reach a logic high.

Comment: yes, Vin and enable pins are both 4.5V

Comment: is it a commercial board, or your own layout, do you have confidence in it is what I mean?

Comment: This is a new board, so you are correct that it's unproven...which is why I'm asking on here.

Comment: Place the link as normal text and someone will hyperlink it for you.

Comment: Measure feedback and comp pin and post the results.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The feedback pin is reading ~13mV and comp pin is showing ~45mV

Comment: anyone have an idea of what's going on? I appreciate the help!

Comment: The FB pin reading is too low.  Remove/disconnect the pot and get a new reading.  It should be around 1.2v for 12v output. If you don't get this, your chip is defective.  If you do get it, your pot is defective.